# What's the performance hit of List.OfType<> where the entire list is that type?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, covariance

I have an architecture where we are passing our data nodes as `IEnumerable<BaseNode>`. It all works great, but in each subclass we want to store these as `List<AnotherNode>` as everything in that class creates and uses `AnotherNode` objects (we have about 15 different subclasses).

The one place using the more strongly typed list doesn't work is the root classes method that returns a type `IEnumerable<BaseNode>` and with the covariance limitations in .net 3.5, that can't be returned. (We have to stay on .net 3.5 for now.)

But if I have `List<AnotherNode> data;` and return `data.OfType<BaseNode>();` - that works fine. So here's my question.

As all of data is of type `BaseNode` - what's the performance hit of this call? Because the alternative is I have to cast in places which has a small performance hit - but it's also a situation where we give up everything knowing it's type.

Comment: I think more code is needed before I can say what the performance hit is.

Comment: In general, the performance cost will be too small to matter. Wait until  you have a real problem.

Comment: If you're at the level where casting items to another type becomes a performance concern, you are likely in a situation where changing your architecture is more important.

Comment: Just remember to call ToList or ToArray before you return it, if this result is used a low. OfType returns an IEnumerable, that will do it's OfType work on each element each time it is enumerated.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - just beat me!

Comment: Good point on the ToList point. It looks like Cast<BaseNode>().ToList() is a good solution here. Thank you all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two minor things:

1. There is a small, but measurable overhead associated with yielding each item in the enumerator.  If you need to care about this because you're in a very tight inner loop, you're actually better off iterating with a for loop on the list directly.  Most likely this doesn't matter.
2. Because the result is `IEnumerable<BaseNode>` and has already been filtered through a yielding enumeration function, subsequent calls to methods like Count() or ElementAt() will not take advantage of optimizations in the LINQ implementation for Lists.  This is also unlikely to be a problem unless you make frequent use of these extension methods and have a very large number of elements.

Comment: +1 for point 2.  Something I didn't consider before but makes perfect sense.

Comment: But if I return Cast<BaseNode>().ToList() then I do get that correct?

Comment: @David, Correct, though, in that case, you incur the overhead of creating a whole new list.  The reason you would want to use ToList() is if you want the return value to be a 'snapshot' of the data, rather than returning a context that could be used to enumerate the underlying data repeatedly.

Comment: So no perfect solution here - oh well... Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Have you seen the [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) Linq operator? It should be more performant than `OfType<T>()`.

Basically there is a condition that is run with `OfType<T>()`

```
if (item is T) {
    yield return (T)item;
}
```

Contrast that with what `Cast<T>()` does:

```
yield return (T)item;
```

Comment: I've created a benchmark for this and it shows the opposite is true: https://gist.github.com/Shazwazza/04e2e5642a316f4a87e52dada2901198